# ES6 compilers browser support

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

It is 2016 and we can use ES6 in browser with code compilers (Traceur, Babel).
We even have this wonderful [table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) to check which features these compilers support.

But I haven't found a single note describing which browsers can run compiled code. If I compile my code with Babel which browsers can run my project?

I haven't found any info at Babel website. There is only phrases like "allow you to use new syntax, right now without waiting for browser support". Am I'm missing something?

Comment: `If I compile my code with Babel which browsers can run my project?` - All browsers which support ES5

Comment: Browser support is detailed under the [Caveats](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/caveats/) page

Answer (score 2):

If you are compiling your code with Babel, then it will run in all the browsers, because what babel does is transpile the es6 code to es5 so it can run in all the browsers.

Comment: Not precisely, since Babel can be configured to target ES3.

Comment: Yes, but given the question i suposed he wanted to transpile it to es5.